# How to disable a custom tooltip for a dataset in Chart.js line chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I have a line chart with 2 datasets, I use custom html tooltips. I would like to disable tooltips for 1 dataset, but i can't seem to figure it out.
All the solution i've seen work for the canvas deafult tooltips...

Answer (score 0):

You can filter tooltips:

```
tooltips: {
    enabled: true,
    filter: function (tooltipItem) {
        var dSet = tooltipItem.datasetIndex;
        if (dSet == 1) {  // <-- dataset index
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    },
    // (....)
```

**EDIT:**
To hide custom tooltips you need to check the dataset from your tooltip function:

```
var customTooltips = function(tooltip) {
    if(tooltip.hasOwnProperty('dataPoints') && tooltip.dataPoints[0] != 'undefined'){
        if(tooltip.dataPoints[0].datasetIndex == 0) // <-- dataset index
            return;
    }
```

Comment: i tried it, but the tooltip is still shown. is there a way to check the result of the filter function result from the custom function?

Comment: Didn't noticed that custom tooltip is used. I added solution.